# How to count duplicate rows in a query in efficient way?

Tags: abap, sap-query

I am creating a report in SAP SQ01/SQ02 whose purpose is to show the number of times a product was picked in the specified time frame.

The data is mainly sourced from table LTAP. I just need to be able to count the number of rows Material XYZ is duplicated in and output the number into an extra field and show the value. Also I want this count to happen in a specified time frame, let's say in the last 30 days, this is to make sure it's up to date and relevant.

The below code works, but it's so slow, it takes a couple of seconds to output the count for just 1 material and I need the report to output top 1000 based on the count. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing?

**DATA TAB**

```
DATA : YEAR(4) TYPE N,
       MTH(2) TYPE N,
       DAY(2) TYPE N,
       YEAR1(4) TYPE N,
       MTH1(2) TYPE N,
       DAY1(2) TYPE N,
       FROM_DATE LIKE SY-DATUM,
       count1 like LTAP-UMREZ.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs_dtab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
DATA: sort_f1 TYPE fieldname.
```

**INITIALIZATION TAB**

```
sort_f1 = 'ltap-matnr'.
```

**Record Processing TAB**

```
YEAR = SY-DATUM(4).
MTH = SY-DATUM+4(2).
DAY = SY-DATUM+6(2).
IF MTH eq 1.
    MTH1 = MTH + 11.
   ELSE.
    MTH1 = MTH - 1.
 ENDIF.
   IF MTH eq 1.
      YEAR1 = YEAR - 1.
        ELSE.
        YEAR1 = YEAR.
   ENDIF.
FROM_DATE(4) = YEAR1.
FROM_DATE+4(2) = MTH1.
FROM_DATE+6(2) = DAY.
```

**END OF SELECTION AFTER TAB**

```
ASSIGN ('%G00[]') TO <fs_dtab>.
IF <fs_dtab> IS ASSIGNED.
  SORT <fs_dtab> BY (sort_f1)
                 DESCENDING.
  DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM <fs_dtab>
  COMPARING (sort_f1).
ENDIF.
```

**Extra Field Code**

In LTAP, field UMREZ is populated with number "1", so I am using it here to count the duplicates.

```
clear count.
Select sum( UMREZ ) as UMREZ
  from *LTAP into COUNT
  where *LTAP~MATNR eq LTAP-MATNR
  and *LTAP~QDATU GE from_date.
```

I expect the report to come out in seconds rather than minutes for a couple of material codes. Alternative code or an improvement to the current one which could accomplish this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `SUM( UMREZ )` for "counting" ?

Comment: Hi, ive added an edit, I was hoping to minimize the amount of code used and use that field for counting as it is populated with a constant 1 and is not actively used otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
DATA materials TYPE RANGE OF matnr.

SELECT
    matnr AS material,
    COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM ltap
  INTO TABLE @DATA(result)
  WHERE matnr IN materials
    AND qdatu >= @from_date
  GROUP BY matnr.
```

Make sure there is an index on the column `MATNR`. In the current S/4HANA, there is one  `HW6` that fits, but it deploys on SAP HANA only and may not be available on older releases.

Comment: Hi, we are running on an older version 13.00.5270.00 I believe the above code won't work, is it just a matter of defining the fields where @ is used?

Comment: @DDoze If you want the best performance, you should create a new **infoset** with an **integrated reading program**, which does the query shown by Florian, and create the query based on it. This way, you won't have to do a count for each LTAP line and delete the duplicate lines before the display.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I did a couple of Infosets/queries but typically its a table join with a bit of code, still fairly new to abap, but I want to learn. As far as I can see when I create a new infoset the "Intergrated Program" option is ticked by default or are you talking about a specific program? And as I mentioned above, we are running an older version of SAP, it doesnt understand the code posted by Florian.

Comment: `13.00.5270.00` it is version of what?

Comment: sorry thats the mssql ver, our basis and abap version is 702, any chance to see the above code in an older version? As it stands, it doesnt work. Thanks.